# Properties window in design view VSTO

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I'm new to VSTO and I can't find a way to open property panel for design view. I'm building a VSTO application for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `Properties Window` on the `View` menu. You can also open it by pressing `F4` or by typing `Properties` in the search box. See [Properties window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/properties-window?view=vs-2022) for more information.